# ASUS P9X79 bios update failed and flashing bios does nothing

Tags: boot, motherboard, bios

I unfortunately decided that the BIOS of my Asus P9X79 Deluxe could use an update. The official list of [updates](https://www.asus.com/Motherboards/P9X79_DELUXE/HelpDesk_BIOS/) suggested that my BIOS 0609 had never been updated. I downloaded the latest version 4801 and soon realized that I can't see the file (in the *EZ flash 2* utility) because it has the format .CAP and the older updates use .ROM.

> **Version 2002:**
>   If your BIOS version is 1203 or older, please install the BIOS Converter and then the converter will update BIOS to 2002.CAP. The BIOS Converter is available in the BIOS Utilities.

Before trying out the converter I tried to do upgrade to 0906. *EZ flash 2* utility ran the installation and when it finished I was left with a black screen.

I tried flashing the BIOS with multiple upgrade versions or the converter but I still can't boot. Some of the versions seem to install (the light flashes) and for some nothing happens (constant light).

All of the components are connected except for hard drives. I tried cleaning CMOS through the red button and took out the battery several times.

Is there a way to get me out of this mess? What should I do?

I greatly appreciate any help, 
Thank you!

Comment: Clearing out the CMOS only restores the default firmware configuration, it does not solve, errors with the firmware itself.  **It sounds like you flashed an incompatible firmware to your device.**

Comment: I definitely ran the official file from asus.com :(

Comment: The firmware load could have simply failed.  The behavior you describe is typically caused by a problem with the firmware.

Comment: Do newer motherboards have similar issues with BIOS updates? Thank you for your comments btw!

Comment: I have owned dozens of motherboards over the years, we are talking multiple decades, I personally have never had a problem.  Your motherboard isn't that old.  `4801` is clearly labeled as a Beta version.  You should have installed each version independently, at least until you got to 1203.  This would have allowed you to upgrade to 2002, and from then on, install the file ASUS has on their website.